# iPad Pro Cordova App Scaling

Tags: cordova, ipad, ionic-framework, scaling

How do you make the iPad Pro app not scale when using Cordova? I figured out a workaround setting initial, minimum, and max scale to .75, but it still appears pixelated. When I look at the status bar on the home screen vs in the app, the app status bar is significantly larger, so I definitely know it's scaling up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured that, since I couldn't find an answer to this on StackOverflow, I'd post my solution to the issue. I got assistance for this answer from http://www.cordovacircus.com/articles/ipad-pro-and-cordova.

Steps:
 1. Create a storyboard in your Xcode project. To open this project, go to `{app root}/platforms/ios/`, and open up the .xcodeproj file.
 2. Drag a view controller into the storyboard. This will operate as your splash screen, so you can add anything you'd like. I only needed to get the scaling fixed so I left mine blank.

 3. Go to general settings by clicking the root of the project inside of Xcode. Scroll down to `App Icons and Launch Images`, and change the `Launch Screen File` to the storyboard file you just created.

Voila! The app should now launch in fullscreen with no scaling.

Comment: I have the opposite problem. I use one unique storyboard for all universal devices. By this way, on the iPhoneX, I can see my app going fullscreen on the entire screen which looks great. But for iPad Pro I would like to scale up the App, like when you use Legacy images instead of Storyboard (the way you did it before solving your problem). My question is: how to use Storyboard for every devices, except for iPad Pro which I want to use a legacy image to scaleUp/displayZoom the app?

Answer (score 1):

Another way I found to do this was to make sure you have the correct splash screen image sizes loaded for this larger device as mentioned here: [iPad Pro incorrect app size](http://jonathanblog2000.blogspot.com/2017/03/ios-cordova-cdvlaunchscreen-storyboard.html)

1. install the Cordova splash screen plugin
2. add the following to your config file

   `<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~comany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~comcom.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~anycom.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~comany.png" />`

Then make those images the following sizes

- Default@2x~universal~anyany.png - 2732x2732
- Default@2x~universal~comany.png - 1278x2732
- Default@2x~universal~comcom.png - 1334x750
- Default@3x~universal~anyany.png - 2208x2208
- Default@3x~universal~anycom.png - 2208x1242
- Default@3x~universal~comany.png - 1242x2208

Then add those image resource png files into `projectRoot/res/screen/ios` folder

Comment: Be aware: Launch Storyboards are cached! If you don’t see the changed image, try rebooting. If that fails, delete the app and reinstall.

Comment: I went with only using `<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />` and maintaining only one single splash screen image.

And you have to use at least Cordova 4.4.0 afaik.