# Cordova Application Width Different From IOS Safari Width

Tags: ios, cordova, safari, width

I'm creating a web application that I'm loading onto an iPad Pro 12.9" via Cordova. If I open the application on the iPad in localhost, `window.innerWidth` is `1024`. However, if I create a Cordova application an open it on the iPad, `window.innerWidth` is `768`. They both have a `window.devicePixelRatio` of `2`.

I have the following tag in `index.html`:

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />`

What is causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the default launch screen file resolution. Follow the steps here: [iPad Pro Cordova App Scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607620/ipad-pro-cordova-app-scaling)